# Problem with multi-sort atoms in Nominal Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm experimenting with Nominal2's support for multi-sort atoms (see [this example in the Nominal package](https://www.isa-afp.org/theories/nominal2/#Atoms.html) and the discussion in Section 5 of [this paper](https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/christian.urban/Publications/nominal-atoms.pdf)). The idea is to define a toy typed λ-calculus in Church's style, that is, where each variable includes its type (e.g. `λxₒ. xₒ`). So, I came up with the following code:

```
theory Scratch
  imports "Nominal2.Nominal2" "Nominal2.Atoms"
begin

(* In this example I'm using "var", "ty" and "Var" from Nominal2.Atoms *)

nominal_datatype exp =
    EVar var
  | EApp exp exp
  | EAbs x::var M::exp binds x in M

(* I want to prove that λxₒ. xₒ = λyₒ. yₒ *)
lemma "EAbs (Var x (TVar ''o'')) (EVar (Var x (TVar ''o''))) = EAbs (Var y (TVar ''o'')) (EVar (Var y (TVar ''o'')))"
  sorry (* cannot prove this! *)

end
```

As shown in the code above, the problem I found is that I cannot even prove the equality of two α-equivalent terms, which, I think, should work out of the box as is the case for single-sort atoms. Having a look at the Nominal2's implementation, it seems to me that the root cause is the lacking of a simproc similar to `alpha_lst` that works on `at_base` instead of `at`. However, since I'm not an expert in the Nominal package, I may very well be missing something.